# 3d plots with large numbers completely black

Tags: plotting, bugs, color

Using Mathematica Student Edition 11.0.1.0 on macOS Sierra 10.12.4, my surface plots turn completely black whenever the numbers on the $z$-axis become too large.

```
Table[{x, y, x^y}, {x, 1, 28}, {y, 1, 10}];
ListPlot3D[Flatten[%, 1]]
```

[image]

If I change the 28 above to a 27, I instead get:

[image]

Is this a bug? Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Both look fine in V11.1.1 Win10

Comment: I see it on 11.0.0.0 on macOS 10.10.5. It's probably a bug, and may have been fixed if Kuba's observations generalize to macs. You can scale the data by 10^12 or something and then do the ticks by hand, or indicate the scaled units.

Comment: Try to use some `ColorFuntion`, say, `ColorFunction->"Rainbow"`.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I did but to no effect.